# Как наложить изображения на изображения php

Tags: php, gd

В общем сам пример работы вот здесь http://goo.gl/FVu7hh
В данном случаи работает клиентская часть только. Я хочу сделать что бы при нажатии В корзину сохраняло результат на сервер картинкой, так как это сделал пользователь. То есть результат должен получится  [вот такого вида.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t7mt.png)

используется две картинки: 1 картинка (png) модель телефона, 2 - загружена пользователем и отцентрована согласно его предпочтению. Но не пойму как можно такое реализовать и можно ли вообще ? Может кто подскажет алгоритм реализации.

**UPD**

```
<?php

function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct){
    $cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);
    imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h);
    imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);
    imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct);
} 

$back_img     = imagecreatefromjpeg('uploads/61203.jpg');
$product_mask = imagecreatefrompng('uploads/Iphone4-4s_1.png');

imagecopymerge_alpha($back_img, $product_mask, 463, 347, 0, 0, 450, 450, 100);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagejpeg($back_img);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ознакомьтесь с функционалом библиотеки [GD](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.image.php)

Заметьте, что Вам нужно будет реализовывать функцию клиентской части — определение координат при центровке изображения с последующей отправкой скрипту. А далее, [по примерам](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecreatefrompng.php).

Библиотека GD хорошо нагружает сервер, имейте это ввиду при разработке.

Comment: Алгоритм подскажет гугл... https://www.google.ru/search?q=php+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83&oq=php+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BD&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.9145j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Могу помочь навести, посмотри [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecopymerge.php). Если вкратце:
создаешь ресурсы обеих картинок (маски телефона и фото юзера) с помощью `imagecreatefrompng`, смотришь комменты к ссылке выше, там предлагается решение для поддержки альфа-канала, берешь функцию затем накладываешь с помощью неё примерно так `imagecopymerge_alpha($background_image, $product_mask, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, 500, 100);`, задав, конечно же, свои размеры и координаты (см. функции для работы с GD и ссылку выше).

Comment: Вроде бы сделал только не могу понять как вычислить правильно координаты от клиента и как их использовать в imagecopymerge_alpha. Получаю средствами js следующие параметры: Object { imgTop: 74, imgLeft: 136, imgWidth: 463, imgHeight: 347, moqupSrc: "image/model/Iphone4-4s_1.png" }.

Comment: Можно попробовать создать пустую картинку, равную по размерам маске телефона, на нее наложить картинку юзера (можно будет применить координаты), и затем сверху маску телефона (с прозрачной областью естественно)

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, речь идет о сервисе для печати на чехлах. В этом случае для типографии нужна будет только сама картинка, без обертки в виде задней части телефона. А если "как будет выглядеть" нужно показать для пользователя сервиса, то лучше использовать средства css, наложив сверху изображения png-маску.

Comment: Да Вы правы,  речь идет о сервисе для печати на чехлах. Ну к примеру если пользователь грузит картинку 2000Х1600, и хочет только нанести на чехол часть картинки, а не всю. Оригинал картинки то само собой я загружаю на сервер, но и нужно загрузить же ту часть которую он хочет что бы была загружена.

Comment: Думаю автору всё-таки понадобится знать позиции картинки, её параметры увеличения и пр. А если заходить и далее, то обязательно нужно итог высылать на почту пользователю! Иначе потом возникнет куча предъяв: "Вы не так напечатали", "Я просил не так". А если у пользователя будет всё на почте, и он подтвердит это нажатием на ссылку (как при активации e-mail) то вариант "Я заказывал не так" - не пройдет. Поэтому нужно использовать не только css...

Comment: GrayHoax, да Вы правы. Нужно будет учесть вариант отправки на почту.

Comment: Могу предложить подсмотреть как это реализовано здесь http://etishtuki.ru